# Laravel - will the use of too many reusable components in blade views slower the page access or put a load on server?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-cache

I'm structuring a webapp in manner to maximize the use of resusable components, by making use of components and slot feature provided by the blade.

My only concern is will the use of too many reusable component slow the page access or put a load on the server? I'm aware that laravel has a feature to cache the compiled blade views but will caching work in this cache ?

Edit : What in the cases where html code is being generated conditionally depending on the state of a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You a right, Laravel cache blade views and you don't need to worry about speed!

Comment: What in the cases where html code is being generated conditionally depending on the state of a variable?

Comment: That has nothing to do with the usage of reusable components. You hit the same performance problem by including everything in a long and repetead monolithic blade template.